# how to solve that random gives false numbers

Tags: c, random

I'm trying to generate random value for sensors in tinyos, nesc. I want to have specific limits but what i get isn't exactly what i want.
I want to get numbers between [nodeID, nodeID+20]
My code is:

```
value = nodeID + rand()%(20 + (1 + nodeID));
```

Any ideas?

Comment: And what *do* you get? I think it's time for you to finally to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: value = nodeID + (rand()%20), if i understood your problem correcty

Comment: `value = nodeID + (rand()%21)`

Comment: NodeID is not fixed. I' m running this for about 10 times. What i want is e.g. for nodeID=2, to get number between [2, 22] but a get [2,24] instead.

Answer (score 0):

To get a value in the range [nodeID, nodeID+20]:

There are a total of 21 values you could get back, so start with `rand() % 21` to give you a value from 0 to 20.

Now add nodeID to this: `nodeID + (rand() % 21)`.  This gives you a value ranging from nodeID to nodeId+20.